# OpenId Connect with php or Java script

Tags: php, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I need to implement SSO in a site that is PHP

When the user clicks on a login button, I need to show the SSO form connecting with an identity server

I don't really know where to start

All I know at present is that I must use OpenID Connect

I am wondering whether it is an option to use Javascript

I have spent ages looking around on google etc but I am struggling to find a good simple tutorial.

Can anyone provide any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

My firm usually recommends [PHPLeague's OAuth2 client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) for PHP integrations. There's is sample code in the README.md, but basically

- Include the relevant Client Key and Secret in the $Provider,
- Make the call to getAuthorizationURL() with the $Provider, which will redirect the user to the login page, and return back to your code with `?code=[stuff]`,
- You can then use the value in `$_GET['code']` to get an access token from the identity provider, and
- using that token you'll be able to use `getAuthenticatedRequest`'s as needed if you need to pull something from a secured API on the identity server, or
- you can also just user information about the `$resourceOwner` that is returned.

The access token has expiry information, etc. and there are functions for refreshing the token as needed. All in all it's really simple to do with PHP.

I avoid JS for OAuth, but I'm pretty sure that's just a personal preference. There are [good javascript libraries](https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso) as well.

*Edit:*

To include OIDC support, make sure you specify the OIDC scope:

`$options = ['scope' => ['openid']];`

and call `getAuthorizationUrl` with the $options array, like:

`$authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);`

Comment: ok thanks there seems to be an insistence that I use OpenId Connect as well

Comment: OAuth is the basis for OIDC... OIDC is just a profile for OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Specifically, with PHPLeague you should use: `$options = ['scope' => ['openid']];` and call `getAuthorizationUrl` with the $options array, like: `$authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);`.

Comment: Thanks for all the above I am not sure where to find the secret from I don’t think that’s in the c# version

Comment: @kallen Is this compatible with an internal identity server using implicit flow?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, never used this particular library with implicit flow. In fact, I've never used any library with the implicit grant because I've never encountered anyone using that due to security concerns with token leakage. See: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-06.html